# $E$-$k$ diagram of hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, hydrogen

The energy of a free (nearly free) electron in a solid (say, metals) is given by  $E=\hbar^2k^2/2m$ where $k$ is the momentum  vector, $\hbar$ is Planck's constant and $m$ is the mass of the electron. This expression denotes a parabola. So the $E$-$k$ diagram of a such an electron is given by,

[image]

How will the $E$-$k$ diagram of a **hydrogen atom** look like?
In a hydrogen atom, there is one electron. This electron is in under the strong potential of the nucleus. So the energy states are discrete. Probably the above relation does not even hold for this system. So, in such a case, what will be the shape of the $E$-$k$ curve?

Comment: In the expression for the energy, h is supposed to be replaced by hcut (or h-hat), i.e., h divided by 2*pi. I don't know how to type hcut here. So I left it like that. Apologies.

Comment: A hydrogen atom is not a solid. The electron is not free or nearly-free. In the hydrogen atom the electron will possibly occupy the states allowed by the solutions to the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: Yes, right. So can we not have any kind of E-k diagram for the hydrogen atom? The parabolic curve which I have shown is just an example of an E-k diagram for a state of matter.

Comment: Each solution to the hydrogen-atom equation has an energy and angular momentum for that state. As stationary states they have no net $k$.

Comment: Okay. So that means, the "k" vector is non-existent for an electron in a hydrogen atom, as these electrons don't move about. They have an angular momentum only. So for such a system, the E-k diagram does not exist at all. Am I thinking along the correct lines?

Answer (score 2):

The E-k diagram (energy-momentum relation) of a freely moving electron refers to plane electron (de Broglie) waves in space, in a periodic crystal potential to Bloch waves. There is no E-k diagram for an electron bound in the hydrogen atom because the orbital wave functions are not plane waves. The translational  movement of the whole hydrogen atom, however, can be described by plane waves with a corresponding E-k (kinetic energy-momentum) relation.